# Add wordpress custom post type data to an external db

Tags: salesforce, wordpress, custom-post-type

This function adds custom post 'event' data into a Salesforce db.  I've tested the function outside of Wordpress and it works flawlessly.  When I test it inside Wordpress by adding a new event, no error is generated and a the data is not inserted into the SF db.  I've also tested this by printing out the $_POST and saw that the data is being collected.  How can I get this display some errors so that I can trouble shoot this?

```
function add_campaign_to_SF( $post_id) {
    global $SF_USERNAME;
    global $SF_PASSWORD;

    if ('event' == $_POST['post-type']) {
        try {
              $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
              $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(CD_PLUGIN_PATH . 'Toolkit/soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
              $mySFlogin = $mySforceConnection->login($SF_USERNAME, $SF_PASSWORD);

              $sObject = new stdclass();
              $sObject->Name = get_the_title( $post_id );
              $sObject->StartDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["events_startdate"]));
              $sObject->EndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["events_enddate"]));
              $sObject->IsActive = '1';

              $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Campaign');

              $ids = array();
                    foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
                        error_log($createResult);
                        array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
                    }

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        error_log($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
                        error_log($e->faultstring);
                        die;
                    }
    }
 }

 add_action( 'save_post', 'add_campaign_to_SF');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) to check for "event" posts. Use [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to write to the PHP error log for additional debugging - check the status of your Salesforce login, etc.

Keep in mind that [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) will run *every* time a post is saved - created or updated - so you might want to do some additional checking (like setting a meta value) before creating a new `Campaign` in Salesforce, otherwise you will end up with duplicates.

```
function add_campaign_to_SF( $post_id ) {
    $debug = true;
    if ($debug) error_log("Running save_post function add_campaign_to_SF( $post_id )");
    if ( 'event' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ){
        if ($debug) error_log("The post type is 'event'");
        if ( false === get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sfdc_id', true ) ){
            if ($debug) error_log("There is no meta value for  'sfdc_id'");
            // add to Salesforce, get back the ID of the new Campaign object
            if ($debug) error_log("The new object ID is $sfdc_id");
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sfdc_id', $sfdc_id );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_campaign_to_SF' );
```

Comment: Is using this wp_insert_post_data filter a better option?

Comment: That gets called on update too... I would set a meta value indicating if you have successfully created an object in SFDC, the ID perhaps

Comment: Check out my edit, it checks the post type, then checks to see if there is already an SFDC Campaign, then it tries to do the save, with lots of debugging messages.

Comment: How can I check if its a new post or a post that's being updated?

Comment: It doesn't really matter - you just care if there is a Campaign in Salesforce, so check to see if you created one and saved its ID to a meta value. If you can't find it, the meta will be false and you can save a new object. If something goes wrong the first time you can just save again and it will re-run until the sfdc_id is saved to the meta value successfully.